# Inputting a multiple tuples in list in Python language

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I created a program that will input an element to tuple then append it into list.

Here is my code:

```
def tuple_and_list():
    my_list = []
    my_tuple = ()
    n_list = int(input("Enter how many element you want in list: "))
    for i in range(4):
        n_tuple = int(input("Enter how many element you want in tuple: "))
        for j in range(n_tuple):
            e_tuple = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            my_tuple = my_tuple + (e_tuple,)
        my_list.append(my_tuple)
    print(my_list)


tuple_and_list()
```

This is the output of my program: `[(1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)]`

It keeps appending the element of the 2nd-4th loop to the 1st loo

How I can my output like this?

```
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: What is your inputs?

Comment: 1 and 2 every loop, @adirabargil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are not mutable; maybe you want to append to a list, and cast to tuple upon storing into my_list?

I added better `input` prompts that let the user clearly see what data is requested, and tabs to further clarify.

```
def tuple_and_list():
    
    my_list = []
    n_list = int(input("Enter how many tuples you want in my_list: "))        
    for idx in range(n_list):
        
        n_tuple = int(input("Enter how many element you want in tuple: "))
        my_input = []
        for jdx in range(n_tuple):
            my_input.append(int(input(f"\ttuple {idx+1}: Enter {jdx+1}th. element: ")))

        my_list.append(tuple(my_input))   # cast the accumulator list to tuple, then append it

    print(my_list)


tuple_and_list()
```

**example run:**

```
Enter how many tuples you want in my_list: 3
Enter how many element you want in tuple: 2
    tuple 1: Enter 1th. element: 1
    tuple 1: Enter 2th. element: 2
Enter how many element you want in tuple: 3
    tuple 2: Enter 1th. element: 3
    tuple 2: Enter 2th. element: 4
    tuple 2: Enter 3th. element: 5
Enter how many element you want in tuple: 2
    tuple 3: Enter 1th. element: 6
    tuple 3: Enter 2th. element: 7
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix is writing `my_tuple = ()` inside 1st for loop.

See below Code

```
def tuple_and_list():
    my_list = []
    n_list = int(input("Enter how many element you want in list: "))
    for i in range(n_list):
        n_tuple = int(input("Enter how many element you want in tuple: "))
        my_tuple = ()
        for j in range(n_tuple):
            e_tuple = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            my_tuple = my_tuple + (e_tuple,)
        my_list.append(my_tuple)
    print(my_list)


print(tuple_and_list())
```